# Adjusting toolbar when viewing site - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a few questions on how to adjust the top toolbar in WordPress when logged in.  Firstly, how do I edit the `site name` section that has the drop down to take you back to dashboard when you are viewing site?  Secondly, How do I edit the mobile versions of the toolbars?

Figured out what I was trying to accomplish, the `remove_node` function at http://codex.wordpress.org/remove_node

This allows me to select the navigations I don't want and remove them from the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Dashboard->Settings->Site Title
2) You can find your admin bar CSS by visiting the following link: http://your.wordpress-site.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css. Replace "your.wordpress-site.com" with the domain and path to your Wordpress installation to view the CSS.

The following Media queries are used for mobile display:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 782px){
    ...
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ...
}
```

If you want to adjust how this displays in your theme, DO NOT overwrite the file in wp-includes. Just override the styles with your own by using more specific selectors in either style.css or a separate stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the Site title is of no use to me?  I figured out what I was trying to do.  But the CSS is great!